# I need to pass UITableView data to detailView Controller

Tags: swift, swift3

I got an issue when I pass the UITableView data to detailViewcontroller like this any one please help me correct this error

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: put code also, we don't even know why are you getting this error and have you made model or not?

Comment: I attached some screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Got your problem,

Step : - IN detailViewcontroller, define variable like that

```
var getImage = UIImage()
var getTitle = String()
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see **newDetails** is an array of dictionary with key and value. You can access the image or anything within a dictionary using its key.

```
if let image = newsDetails[indexPath.row]["yourImageKeyNameFromNewsDetails"] as? String {
        Storyboard?.getImage = UIImage(named: image) ?? UIImage(named: "yourPlaceHolderImage")
}
```

I hope this explains you.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Madushan Senavirathna,

From your provided images, I see that newsDetails is array of [Sting:Any] which will return object of [String:Any].

But you are assigning object to image and string which I observe from given image like :

```
    Storyboard?.getImage = newsDetails[indexPath.row]
    Storyboard?.getTitle = newsDetails[indexPath.row]
```

I found that problem is in above syntax.

Ideal syntax to get images from your object are as below :

```
    if let imageString : String = newsDetails[indexPath.row]["imageKeyFromObject"]
    {
       Storyboard?.getImage = You need to handle image string as per your requirement (if local file name than handle it with UIImage(named: imageString) or if it is dynamic content from server then you have to handle it with url)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to pass data from tableview diselect to details page view controller and in that detail page view controller need to declare that variable correctly..

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cellData = newsDetails[indexPath.row] {
        if let vc = YourDetail page ViewController as? DetailPageController {
            vc.details = cellData
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
   }
```

Comment: In Details page Viewcontroller you can set value from details variable.